# Cannot get a very basic program to produce any output whatsoever

Tags: java, output, java.util.scanner

I cannot get the Pearson MyProgrammingLab to produce any output from this code and several other programs like it. But the code works perfectly fine in other IDEs. Is there an error in the Scanner construction or anything else basic that I am overlooking?

I have exhausted so many solutions and still no luck. There is just simply no output when the program is checked, and cites it as a logic error.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Area {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the side: ");
        double s = input.nextDouble();
        double area = (6 * Math.pow(s, 2)) / (4 * Math.tan(Math.PI/6));
        System.out.println("The area of the hexagon is " + area);
        }
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is what the ouput when checked would display:

```
Given the following was entered from the keyboard:
5.5⏎

you displayed:

instead of:
Enter◦the◦side:The◦area◦of◦the◦hexagon◦is◦78.59⏎
```

Comment: Two things 1. The main class should be public 2. Enter some value in the console

Comment: I'd expect Pearson MyProgrammingLab to have information on how it expects the input to be entered. I'd also expect it requires one has an account to find out.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with this code (and, no, the main class does not need to be public, that's a red herring comment). The problem therefore lies with whatever 'My Programming Lab' is, and/or the way you have configured it, and/or the way you are using it.

Comment: It is MyProgrammingLab, you cannot declare it public without an error message. So you just leave it as class. Also, I do input a double value into the console on other IDEs, it works fine and displays correct output. There is no console on MyProgrammingLab. The problem is it apparently produces no output at all on that environment. Like nothing, not even the user prompt for input.

Comment: "I do input a double value into the console on other IDEs". This program needs input. If it doesn't get input it will just sit there and wait after its initial output of "Enter the side: ". This isn't a programming problem. This is a an issue of how to use a particular website.

Comment: I did not explain that part well. The Lab will input values into the code and check to see if your output matches their expected output. When it compares it to mine, it is simply blank - as if the software cannot even input values into my code (even though you can on other IDEs) and thus no output. I guess I'm asking for someone who has had to use this learning software before if they know.

Comment: On the Pearson Site, I found their support page:  https://mlm.pearson.com/northamerica/myprogramminglab/students/support/index.html.  It has a link for contacting Technical Support.  Try that.  'Cos I think there is something wrong with MyProgrammingLab if it is telling you that your program produces no output.

Comment: Having said that, the output you are getting suggests that it *doesn't* expect a space after the colon and it *does* expect the result to be printed with exactly 2 digits after the decimal point.  You should fix those things and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks for that support contact info. I guess its the only thing left. Your idea was good but did not work, still no output. Also, the outputs that the software checks with is all 2 digits after decimal anyways by default. Even if this was the case, there should be output displayed, it would just be the wrong output. I appreciate all the assistance.